# BigQuery calculate grand totals row

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to add row with grand totals under my result set, like ms-sql ROLLUP operator? I want to avoid using extra query for this totals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited: BigQuery now supports the ROLLUP operator. See the query reference [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupby) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! There is a special form for feature requests? Or it's applicable to ask you here? :)

Comment: You can file feature requests here: http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list. But we also look at StackOverflow and will prioritize questions that get a lot of votes.

Comment: @KirillSolokhov - BigQuery now has support for GROUP BY ROLLUP

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Since this question was posted, BigQuery did implement support `GROUP BY ROLLUP` clause compatible with SQL Standard. It is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupby